# How to re-use multiple data annotations for multiple properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I want to use the following data annotations:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid price entered, please re-check the price and try again.")]
[Range(0, 999999.99, ErrorMessage = "The price must be less than £999999.99")]
```

For all price properties in my classes but I do not want to have to reuse the annotations and want to combine them into, for example, [PriceValidation] and print this above all properties.
Can this be done? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create own [custom validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-attributes) which will incapsulate needed logic. Something like this for starters:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class PriceValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        if (stringValue != null && !Regex.IsMatch(stringValue))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid price entered, please re-check the price and try again.");
        }

        var doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(value);
        if (doubleValue > 999999.99 || doubleValue < 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The price must be less than £999999.99");
        }
        
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Also you can look into using [fluent validation library](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html).